# Inject User-defined HTML Into Directive's Template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to populate the contents of a  with HTML supplied by the user. Specifically:

```
app.directive("myTable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      rows: '@'
    },
    template: 
      '<table>' + 
        '<tbody>' + 
          '<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">' +
            '<td>{{row.html}}</td>' + 
          '</tr>' +
        '</tbody>' + 
      '</table>'
  };
});
```

However, {{row.html}} is inserted as text. Thank you

Comment: How is this "supplied by the user" if you're defining it in the directive's template?

Comment: Oh, I see. `row.html` contains the html code. Well, if your user-supplied html does not contain angular bindings, you're fine. Otherwise, you need to `$compile` the html content whenever you add it.

Comment: Apologies, poorly worded. row.html comes from the user who uses my directive and passes in a collection of rows via the directive's scope

Comment: The HTML does not contain any angular constructs. In most cases the HTML is just <img> tags. Despite this, Angular renders {{row.html}} as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to evaluate the expression:

```
<td ng-bind-html="row.html"></td>
```